# How display link after product name in cart in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to display link after product name in cart page in magneto.

I have tried using "**Renderer**" but it is not working. I have added below code in "Renderer".

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer{

    public function getProductName()
    {
        $name = parent::getProductName();
        $item = $this->_item;
        $results_data = $item->getOptionByCode("customizer_data");
        if($results_data){
            $results = unserialize($results_data);
            $imagePathFull = $results['image']['url'];
            return "Custom - ".$name." - <a target='_blank' href='{$imagePathFull}'>View Image</a>";
        }else{
            return $name;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to add link using additional information block but it is not working. I have added below code in **Config.xml** file

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.productcustomizer.additional" template="productcustomizer/checkout/cart/additional.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: By default it has the product link on the image and the name too. Also if you have done any changes see this function `getProductUrl()` inside `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` class. You can call that inside your `getProductName()`.

Comment: But I want to display another (Custom Image) Link, When you click on link then image will be open in new tab.

Comment: Ohh..sorry i thought product link. My bad.

Comment: But you cant do it inside `getProductName()` function. It gets called inside `anchor` tag. You just cant add another `href` inside it. Like this `<a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">` . You cant add another `href` inside a `anchor` tag.

Comment: It's OK, No problem.

Comment: Yes, so i have try using additional information block but it is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132197/discussion-between-chetan-khandla-and-kingshuk-deb).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code in config.xml file. Now it is working fine

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="additional.product.info" template="productcustomizer/checkout/cart/additional.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```